# Simultaneous print on log file and console in Google Colab

Tags: python, logging, google-colaboratory, tee

I have a very computationally costly code to execute in Google Colab, which takes a very long time to finish executing. The thing is that I generate a log file from my execution using prints, with the following function:

```
log_file = None
execution_uid = env['EXEC_ID']
log_folder_path = '../logs'

class Tee:
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            if hasattr(f, "write"):
                if f.name == "<stdout>":
                    # Handle tqdm separately
                    try:
                        f.write(obj)
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
                else:
                    f.write(obj)
                f.flush()
    
    def flush(self):
        for f in self.files:
            f.flush()
            
def setLogFile(execution_uid = None):
    if execution_uid == None:
        execution_uid = env['EXEC_ID']

    log_file_path = log_folder_path + "/" + str(execution_uid) + '_execution_log_'+ str(int(time.time())) +'.log'
    if env['LOGS']:
        os.makedirs(log_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
        log_file = open(log_file_path, "w")
        
        print("\n\n \t\t Results of the execution will be available at: " + log_file_path + "\n\n")
        encoding = sys.stdout.encoding if sys.stdout.encoding else 'utf-8'
        # Create a Tee object to duplicate the output
        tee = Tee(sys.stdout, io.TextIOWrapper(log_file.buffer, encoding=encoding, errors='ignore'))
        sys.stdout = tee
        return log_file
    else:
        print("\n\n \t\t  Using CONSOLE as execution printer \n\n")
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  # Reset sys.stdout to the original value
        return None
```

This works fine in general, but in Google Colab, if the execution does not finish and the environment disconnects or there is a crash, the log file is not generated (while it is if I manually stop the cell from executing or if a crash occurs locally not using Colab). My question is, how can I generate this file "on the fly" so that even if the execution crashes or the environment disconnects I do not loose that log information?